# How to remove multiple rows from QTable Widget?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt4

I want to remove multiple rows which are selected in the QTableWidget . can anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove multiple items at once, The tips, is begin delete the rows from the bottom. i'm sorry im not a VS2008 developer, but this solution can be easy convert to VS2008 code. Here the Python code. Sorry for the late response :)

```
# Delete the selected mytable lines
deleteRows(self.mytable.selectionModel().selectedRows())

# DeleteRows function
def deleteRows(self, rows):
        # Get all row index
        indexes = []
        for row in rows:
            indexes.append(row.row())

        # Reverse sort rows indexes
        indexes = sorted(indexes, reverse=True)

        # Delete rows
        for rowidx in indexes:
            self.mytable.removeRow(rowidx)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove some rows at the end of the table, you can try using setRowCount(int row).

i was looking for a way to remove multiple selected rows from different places in the table some time back too.

i ended up iterating through my selected list from the bottom to delete my table.

Comment: I dont want to remove from bottom . I want to remove multiple rows which are selected from any place.

Answer (score 0):

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem*> itemList = widget->selectedItems();
for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    widget->removeCellWidget(itemList.at(i)->row(), itemList.at(i)->column());
}
```

Comment: There is no way to delete multiple items at once

Comment: Thanks for your help . But i couldn't able to remove atleast one item from the Table :(

Comment: yes i can able to select the items . but unable to delete it from table .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help :

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem*> selected_itms = ur_table->selectedItems();
while( !selected_itms.isEmpty() )
{
    QTableWidgetItem *itm = selected_itms.at(0);
    ur_table->removeRow(itm->row());
    selected_itms = ui.tblw_entries->selectedItems();
}
```

Comment: What is selected_rows ? How is it set?

Comment: @Ashot ~> It was a mistake !

Comment: the one remains `QTableWidgetItem *itm = selected_rows.at(0);` also it is better to remove selected rows in inverse order